# How do I save a URL to a file after confirming the content type?

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to download a file from a URL if the file is a specific content type.  The URL could either serve an html or pdf page, and I only want to save the pdf files.  My attempt at doing this is below:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
connection.connect();
String contentType = connection.getContentType();

if (contentType.equals("application/pdf")) {
      org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
}
```

The contentType is being fetched correctly, but the call to `copyURLToFile(url,file);` results in the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:999)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:848)
```

If I remove the lines of code for fetching the contentType, and just have the call to `copyURLToFile(url,file)`, the file is downloaded and saved successfully.  Am I mishandling my `HttpURLConnection` in some way that's causing my connection to be reset?

I've also noticed that if I set a breakpoint on the `if(contentType.equals("application/pdf")` line and wait a few seconds, then the call to `copyURLToFile` succeeds without the connection being reset.  Am I introducing some kind of race condition that always fails?

Comment: do reconnect after you fetched content type or play with connection.setReadTimeOut

Comment: I think [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) should not return you the content of the file.

Comment: The call to `copyURLToFile` creates a new connection, so it shouldn't use a HEAD request to get the input stream from the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the open connection to read the data:

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(file));
```

No need to open another connection, possibly the server resets the connection?

EDIT: Didn't the the request method setting, but with a GET this works for me:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    String contentType = connection.getContentType();
    System.out.println("content-type: " + contentType);
    IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream("/temp/test.html"));
}
```

EDIT: Or that way, if you want to check the header with a HEAD request first:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
String contentType = connection.getContentType();
System.out.println("content-type: " + contentType);
connection.disconnect();
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream("/temp/test.html"));
connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but I wasn't sure if I had to reset the connection somehow after making the HEAD request.  This call doesn't result in an exception, but the contents of the URL are not saved to the file. An empty file gets created.  I tried changing the request method back to GET via `connection.setRequestMethod("GET")`, but still no luck.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the HEAD request method in your original code. But with a GET (see edited answer) it works for me. All this sounds like a connection reset done by the server, not a problem with your code.

Comment: Yes, it works if I use a GET request.  I was just trying to get a HEAD request to work so that I didn't fetch the contents of the file before confirming that it was a content type I wanted to save.  Thanks for your answer!  I might give up on getting the HEAD request to work and just waste the bandwidth... :)

Comment: I did a third version (see answer), for google.com it works checking the content-type with a HEAD request first and then getting the content using a GET request.

Comment: I believe that if you use the GET request, read the content-type from the header, and decide not to read the body, then you haven't wasted any bandwidth.

And this is superior to closing the connection and opening a new one, since establishing new connections increases latency.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try closing the connection after you read the HEAD?

```
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
   connection.connect();
   String contentType = connection.getContentType();
   connection.close();
```

The FileUtils should then open a new connection and your problem might be solved.

Comment: I had tried adding a `connection.disconnect()` after my call to `getContentType()`, but I still end up with the same exception.